# Give an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of the following: For all $a>0$, $f(x) = 1/x$ is continuous at $a$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I'm fairly new to epsilon-delta proofs as we've just started learning them. I'm very confused about choosing a delta for this, do we have to choose an arbitrary delta with a range? Why so?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @RobertZ , it's a try and not a tray...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $|x-a|<a/2; a>0;$

Then $a/2 <x <(3/2)a;$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta =\min (a/2, \epsilon(a^2/2))$;

Then $|x-a|<\delta$ implies

$|1/x-1/a|=$

$\dfrac{|x-a|}{|xa|} \le (2/a^2)|x-a| <$

$(2/a^2)\delta < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you so much, just to confirm, we have assumed that $\delta$ will be less than 1, right? Also, I'm still a little confused about the selection of $\delta$ as being the minimum of a/2 and $\epsilon$($a^2$/2). I'm a little confused about how the $\epsilon$($a^2$/2) came about. Thank you so much!

Comment: BoyAcc. Look at the last line with denominator $|xa|$. Need to bound $|x|$ below (why?), to get $\le$ $(2/a^2)|x-a|$. We have $|x-a| <\delta$. If we take the min as above we can use the inequalities. Ask again if not OK.